# MVC: Update Grand Children Using UpdateModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

I have a nested view model and I'm using it to update (edit) the form. I'm able to update the Parent and Children using UpdateModel but not able to update the Grand Children. I tried "Answers" and "Questions.Answers" for the UpdateModel prefix name but it's not updating. Any help is appreciated!

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SurveyViewModel request)
    {
        try
        {
            var dbrecord = Survey.Get(request.SurveyID, Survey.FetchType.SurveyID);
            UpdateModel(dbrecord); // Working
            UpdateModel(dbrecord.SurveyQuestions, "Questions"); // Working

            // Not Working
            for (var i = 0; i < dbrecord.SurveyQuestions.Count; i++)
            {
                UpdateModel(dbrecord.SurveyQuestions[i].SurveyAnswers, "Questions[" + i + "].Answers");
            }

            dbrecord.Save();

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

View Model

```
public class SurveyViewModel
{
    public int SurveyID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<QuestionsRequest> Questions { get; set; }

    public class QuestionsRequest
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }

        public List<AnswersRequest> Answers { get; set; }

        public class AnswersRequest
        {
            public string Answer { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround and not a best practice, but have you tried setting the entity state to EntityState.Modified for each item in the for loop before calling UpdateModel?